# Eclipse Ecore Modelling

Tags: eclipse, uml, ecore

Imagine you work for a medium IT company. The number of employees
increased significantly over the last few months. Thus your boss likes to
have a model of the company's processes. Therefore, he assigned you
the task to implement a software system, which enables you to model
the processes. In a first analysis you found the following constrains:

- A process has a name, a state and contains either multiple work steps or a sub-process. Basically a sub-process is the same like a       process.
- The state can have the following values: planning, in process, finished, failed. Every work step has a duration, a priority (high, medium, low) and knows its predecessor and successor.
- In addition, every work step can have multiple persons, which are       responsible for the step.
- Responsible persons can be divided in internal and external employees. All employees have a name, an id, and an e-mail address. Besides that, internal employees have a room  number as well.
- Because you want to improve the whole workflow, you assume that every work step belongs to a process or sub-process.
- Every process and sub-process is able to calculate its duration.
- In addition, every sub-process or process has one or more outcomes.

**Task:**
Model the given information into a class diagram. Doing this, also respect the principle of information hiding.

I have defined my modelling like this. I wonder what kind of a relationship would between person and work(composition. aggregation or association)? How would I decide in a correct way?

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP seeks someone to do his homework.

Comment: It is not a homework. I wonder whät kind of a relationship would between person and work(composition. aggregation or association)? How would I decide in a correct way?

Comment: In that case, please edit your question and write it as such.